Trying to concatenate a row to a matrix in tensorflow
I have time series data in 4 channels and am trying to generate a sequence of length N using my model. I am determining N from the input data supplied to my sequence generation function:
def generate_sequence(self, input_data):
    predicted_sequence = tf.convert_to_tensor(input_data, dtype=tf.float32)
    data_shape = predicted_sequence.shape
    for i in range(len(predicted_sequence)):
        model_input = tf.reshape(predicted_sequence, shape=data_shape)
        result = self.model(model_input)
        predicted_sequence = tf.concat([predicted_sequence[:, 1:, :], result], 0)
    return predicted_sequence

This causes the following error:
ConcatOp : Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal: shape[0] = [1,1439,4] vs. shape[1] = [1,1,4] [Op:ConcatV2] name: concat
This seems to suggest that I am using the wrong method to generate my sequence (I naively wrote this function assuming that tensorflow tensors would behave like numpy arrays). In my loop I start with my input data:
[[[a1, b1, c1, d1]
  [a2, b2, c2, d2]
  ...
  [aN, bN, cN, dN]]

and I generate a prediction using my model:
[[aP1, bP1, cP1, dP1]]

My intention at this point is to remove the first entry in the input data, as it is the oldest row of data, and add the predicted data to the end:
[[[a2, b2, c2, b2]
  [a3, b3, c3, d3]
  ...
  [aN, bN, cN, dN]
  [aP1, bP1, cP1, dP1]]]

From here the loop is run until the entire sequence contains predictions for the next N rows of data.
Is there another tensorflow method that is better suited to this or am I missing something in the tf.concat method?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Everything is good except the axis of concatenation. It should be axis=1.
def generate_sequence(self, input_data):
predicted_sequence = tf.convert_to_tensor(input_data, dtype=tf.float32)
data_shape = predicted_sequence.shape
for i in range(len(predicted_sequence)):
    model_input = tf.reshape(predicted_sequence, shape=data_shape)
    result = self.model(model_input)
    predicted_sequence = tf.concat([predicted_sequence[:, 1:, :], result], axis=1)
return predicted_sequence

The rule of thumb is "all the tensors should possess the same shape in all the axes except the concatenating axis"

This seems to have been what was causing my troubles, thank you. Though now I have a new problem. My model seems to work fine using this for small sequence lengths, eg 200, but for long sequence lengths, eg 1500, it causes an internal error in the LSTM layer. Do you know what might be causing this?

Without knowing the error, we could not resolve it. Can you please post the error? If needed, you can open a new question.
